# codeblocks abbreviations complete without pressing ctrl+j or any additional key

Tags: autocomplete, codeblocks, abbreviation

How can I enable codeblocks to complete the word without pressing any other additional key?

For example, everytime I write `ifb` if should complete with

```
if () 
{

}
```

, even if I don't press ctrl+j after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this feature is not available right now and possible it would be in the future.
([link](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,18431.new.html#new))